# Mixing multiprocessing Pool (producers) with Process (consumer)

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am processing a large csv file in chunks and I write the output to another file. For the processing bit I have the following code:

```
def process_data(self):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

    for result in pool.imap(self.process_data_chunk, self.data_chunks):
        pass
```

At the moment, process_data_chunk also writes to the output file for which it needs a lock. What I'd like to do is for `process_data_chunk` to put the chunk in a `multiprocessing.Queue` and I'd like a separate process to consume from this queue. I'm not sure if I can do this? Can I combine `Pool` with a single `Process` where the `Pool` is the producer and the `Process` is the consumer?

Comment: You should use the sharing between processes feature as mentioned here : https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: You can use a `multiprocessing.Queue`. Use `put` to place the results of the processing on the queue, and then another `multiprocessing.Process` can `get` data from the queue.

Comment: @JohnAnderson How? Where do I create the pool? How do I start it and join it? I've thought about a different design but this would be interesting to get to the bottom of.

Comment: You want to start a separate process for writing to the file so you can avoid the lock?